# Extracting string between html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

In my CakePHP view file, I have two elements

```php
echo $this->Form->create('Shift', array('id' => 'myform'));
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('id' => 'my_user_id', 'type'=>'text'));
```

and some Javascript that confirms something for the user.

```php
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  alert("Creating shift for " + $("#my_user_id").val());
});
});
');
?>
```

So if my HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="input select required">
<label for="my_user_id">User</label>
<select name="data[Shift][user_id]" id="my_user_id" required="required">
<option value="1">john doe</option>
<option value="2">john johnson</option>
```

how can I access the values between the option tags?  As in, "john doe" and "john johnson"?

Comment: Do you want to do this with JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `text` of `option` using `each()` on option

```
$("#my_user_id option").each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you want selected text then use option:selected

```
 $("#my_user_id option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map to get an array of all texts:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Zacr4/)

```
var texts = $("#my_user_id option").map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

or if just text of the selected option:

```
var text = $("#my_user_id option:selected").text();
```